# Device button presses not allways detected iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `JPSVolumeButtonHandler` to detect presses on the iPhones volume buttons. I have noticed some strange behavior on `iOS 13` namely while UP volume presses are detected most of the time DOWN button presses are not, especially when the presses are in quick succession. 
`JPSVolumeButtonHandler` uses `KVO` to monitor volume changes for this:

```
 [self.session addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:sessionVolumeKeyPath
               options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
               context:sessionContext];
```

But the `observeValueForKeyPath:...` doesn't seem to be called when the down button is pressed.

**What could I do to improve the detection of the down volume button?**

Comment: [Documentation for `outputVolume`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616533-outputvolume?language=objc) says that it's compatible with `KVO`.

I assume that some events aren't sent properly by `AVAudioSession` itself.

Can you try to remove options when calling `-[NSObject addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context]`?

Comment: Also, when I had a project which used `MPVolumeView`, it wasn't working properly when I wanted the volume view to be hidden. Seems like `AVAudioSession` tries to detect is there any **not hidden** `MPVolumeView` instance in the view hierarchy.


I had to set `alpha` to `CGFloatMin` rather than setting `isHidden = true` or `alpha = 0`

Comment: [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT, 0, 0)]; so it shouldn't be vissible... I can't remove the options from that call, it doesn't compile without them

Comment: No, what you are doing with `MPVolumeView` is moving far enough and setting `height` and `width` to zero. iOS can detect it and mark it as `invisible` and will not tell any button events. You probably what to put view as it was showing something (like `CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 5)`) but set `alpha = CGFLOAT_MIN + 0.01`. 

It will visually invisible while UIKit detects it `visible`